# Clear Heartland iFrame inputs without reloading the iFrames

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I am using Heartland Payment Gateway JavaScript SDK on my POS web application for credit card payments. The POS enables the user to split the payment into different credit card payments. For that, I am opening the Heartland Iframe form in a bootstrap modal popup. But due to CORS error in Chrome, I am unable to clear the form fields using JavaScript when a payment is added. Also, I searched the Heartland API documentation and found nothing except a `setText()` function that is also not working. As a workaround, I am reinitializing the form but that's not giving a good experience to users because it reloads Iframe.

Here is the code:

```js
(function (document, Heartland) {
  var state = {
    cardNumberValid: false,
    cardCvvValid: false,
    cardExpirationValid: false
  };
    // Create a new `HPS` object with the necessary configuration
    var hps = new Heartland.HPS({
      publicKey: 'pkapi_cert_jKc1FtuyAydZhZfbB3',
      type:      'iframe',
      // Configure the iframe fields to tell the library where
      // the iframe should be inserted into the DOM and some
      // basic options
      fields: {
        cardNumber: {
          target:      'iframesCardNumber',
          placeholder: '•••• •••• •••• ••••'
        },
        cardExpiration: {
          target:      'iframesCardExpiration',
          placeholder: 'MM / YYYY'
        },
        cardCvv: {
          target:      'iframesCardCvv',
          placeholder: 'CVV'
        },
        submit: {
            value: 'Pay $10.00',
            target:       'iframesSubmit'
        }
      },
      // Collection of CSS to inject into the iframes.
      // These properties can match the site's styles
      // to create a seamless experience.
      style: {
        'input': {
          'background': '#fff',
          'border': '1px solid',
          'border-color': '#bbb3b9 #c7c1c6 #c7c1c6',
          'box-sizing': 'border-box',
          'font-family': 'serif',
          'font-size': '16px',
          'line-height': '1',
          'margin': '0 .5em 0 0',
          'max-width': '100%',
          'outline': '0',
          'padding': '0.5278em',
          'vertical-align': 'baseline',
          'height' : '50px',
          'width' : '100% !important'
        },
        '#heartland-field': {
          'font-family':'sans-serif',
          'box-sizing':'border-box',
          'display': 'block',
          'height': '50px',
          'padding': '6px 12px',
          'font-size': '14px',
          'line-height': '1.42857143',
          'color': '#555',
          'background-color': '#fff',
          'border': '1px solid #ccc',
          'border-radius': '0px',
          '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075)',
          'box-shadow': 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075)',
          '-webkit-transition': 'border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s',
          '-o-transition': 'border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s',
          'transition': 'border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s',
          'width' : '100%'
        },  
        '#heartland-field[name=submit]': {   
          'background-color':'#36b46e',
          'font-family':'sans-serif',
          'text-transform':'uppercase',
          'color':'#ffffff',
          'border':'0px solid transparent'
        } ,
        '#heartland-field[name=submit]:focus': {   
          'color':'#ffffff',
          'background-color':'#258851',
          'outline':'none'
        } , 
        '#heartland-field[name=submit]:hover': {   
          'background-color':'#258851'
        } ,          
        '#heartland-field-wrapper #heartland-field:focus' : {
          'border':'1px solid #3989e3',
          'outline':'none',
          'box-shadow':'none',
          'height':'50px'
        },
        'heartland-field-wrapper #heartland-field' : {
          'height':'50px'
        },
        'input[type=submit]' : {
          'box-sizing':'border-box',
          'display': 'inline-block',
          'padding': '6px 12px',
          'margin-bottom': '0',
          'font-size': '14px',
          'font-weight': '400',
          'line-height': '1.42857143',
          'text-align': 'center',
          'white-space': 'nowrap',
          'vertical-align': 'middle',
          '-ms-touch-action': 'manipulation',
          'touch-action': 'manipulation',
          'cursor': 'pointer',
          '-webkit-user-select': 'none',
          '-moz-user-select': 'none',
          '-ms-user-select': 'none',
          'user-select': 'none',
          'background-image': 'none',
          'border': '1px solid transparent',
          'border-radius': '4px',
          'color': '#fff',
          'background-color': '#337ab7',
          'border-color': '#2e6da4'
        },
        '#heartland-field[placeholder]' :{
          'letter-spacing':'3px'
        },
        '#heartland-field[name=cardCvv]' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/cvv1.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'63px 40px',
        },
        'input#heartland-field[name=cardNumber]' : {
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-inputcard-blank@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'55px 35px'},
        '#heartland-field.invalid.card-type-visa' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-saved-visa@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'83px 88px',
          'background-position-y':'-44px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.valid.card-type-visa' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-saved-visa@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right top',
          'background-size' :'82px 86px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.invalid.card-type-discover' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-saved-discover@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'85px 90px',
          'background-position-y' : '-44px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.valid.card-type-discover' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-saved-discover@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'85px 90px',
          'background-position-y' : '1px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.invalid.card-type-amex' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-savedcards-amex@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'50px 90px',
          'background-position-y':'-44px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.valid.card-type-amex' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-savedcards-amex@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right top',
          'background-size' :'50px 90px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.invalid.card-type-mastercard' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-saved-mastercard.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'62px 105px',
          'background-position-y':'-52px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.valid.card-type-mastercard' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-saved-mastercard.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'62px 105px',
          'background-position-y':'-1px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.invalid.card-type-jcb' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-saved-jcb@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right',
          'background-size' :'55px 94px',
          'background-position-y':'-44px'
        },
        '#heartland-field.valid.card-type-jcb' :{
          'background':'transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-saved-jcb@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat right top',
          'background-size' :'55px 94px',
          'background-position-y':'2px'
        },
        'input#heartland-field[name=cardNumber]::-ms-clear' : {
          'display':'none'
        }
      },
      // Callback when a token is received from the service
      onTokenSuccess: function (resp) {
        if (state.cardNumberValid && state.cardCvvValid && state.cardExpirationValid) {
            alert('Here is a single-use token: ' + resp.token_value);
        } else {
            alert('Invalid Expiration Date or CVV.');
        }
      },
      // Callback when an error is received from the service
      onTokenError: function (resp) {
        alert('There was an error: ' + resp.error.message);
      },
      // Callback when an event is fired within an iFrame
    onEvent: function (event) {
      state[event.source + 'Valid'] = event.classes.indexOf('valid') !== -1;
      console.log(state);
    }
    });

    // Attach a handler to interrupt the form submission
    Heartland.Events.addHandler(document.getElementById('iframes'), 'submit', function (e) {
      // Prevent the form from continuing to the `action` address
      e.preventDefault();
      // Tell the iframes to tokenize the data
      hps.Messages.post(
        {
          accumulateData: true,
          action: 'tokenize',
          message: 'pkapi_cert_jKc1FtuyAydZhZfbB3'
        },
        'cardNumber'
      );
    });
  }(document, Heartland));
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

label[for=iframesCardNumber], label[for=iframesCardExpiration], label[for=iframesCardCvv] {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #555;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#ss-banner {
    background: transparent url(https://github.com/hps/heartland-php/blob/master/examples/end-to-end/assets/images/ss-shield@2x.png?raw=true) no-repeat left center;
    height: 40px;
    background-size: 280px 34px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}

.form-row {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://hps.github.io/token/2.1/securesubmit.js"></script>
<!-- The Payment Form -->

<div class="form-wrapper">

  <form id="iframes" action="" method="GET">
  <div id="ss-banner"></div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="iframesCardNumber">Card Number:</label>
      <div id="iframesCardNumber"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="iframesCardExpiration">Card Expiration:</label>
      <div id="iframesCardExpiration"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="iframesCardCvv">Card CVV:</label>
      <div id="iframesCardCvv"></div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div id="iframesSubmit"></div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had the same issue and could not come to a solution that didn't involve some reloading. Here's what I did:

```
var iframes = document.getElementById('newCreditCardForm').getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    $.each(iframes, function (index, iframe) {
        var src = iframe.src;
        iframe.src = '';
        setTimeout(function () { iframe.src = src; }, 100);
    });
```

Basically I hid the form and force reloaded each field's iframe individually. The timeout of 100ms was necessary because Chrome wouldn't reload the iframe if the src was changed back immediately.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).